# What query to run to determine Amazon Athena version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'd like to determine what version of Amazon Athena I'm connected to by running a query. Is this possible? If so, what is the query?

Searching Google, SO, and AWS docs have not found an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "version of Athena"? As a managed service, there is only ever one version of Athena available. Have you seen a version number somewhere?

Comment: Version as in: "what features are supported?" They must do releases and as they add new features how do you know if you've been upgraded to the version that supports them? For example, Redshift release notes versus when you're upgraded is weeks. The answer to this question in Redshift's SQL dialect would be `select version()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Redshift** launches as a cluster, with virtual machines being used for that specific cluster. The cluster must be specifically updated between versions because it is continuously running and is accessible by only one AWS account. Think of it as software running on your own virtual machines.

From [Amazon Redshift Clusters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html):

> Amazon Redshift provides a setting, Allow Version Upgrade, to specify whether to automatically upgrade the Amazon Redshift engine in your cluster if a new version of the engine becomes available.

**Amazon Athena**, however, is a fully-managed service. There is no cluster to be created -- you simply provide your query and it uses the metastore to know where to find data. Think of it just like Amazon S3 -- many servers provide access to multiple AWS customers simultaneously.

From [Amazon Athena – Interactive SQL Queries for Data in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-athena-interactive-sql-queries-for-data-in-amazon-s3/):

> Behind the scenes, Athena parallelizes your query, spreads it out across hundreds or thousands of cores, and delivers results in seconds.

As a fully-managed service, there is only ever one version of Amazon Athena, which is the version that is currently available.